# python3 list element mapping to sum element

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm

I have a list 'L'

```
L = [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5')]
```

I want this list to

```
[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]
```

which is sum of element.
What is appropriate code? I want shortest code 
Use map method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like homework, but OK.

We need to transform the strings inside the tuples into ints, and then sum them, there are a trillion ways of doing this. This is a general solution so it works even if the tuples in the original list have variable lengths.

First using map as you want

```
list(map(lambda tup: sum(map(int,tup)), L))
```

The list call is just used to create a list from the map object.

You can also use list comprehensions

```
[sum(int(x) for x in tup) for tup in L]
```

You can also mix and match the map in the comprehension call like this to get the shortest code.

```
[sum(map(int,tup)) for tup in L]
```

Comment: thank you! It is not homework. This problem is part of my algorithm problem. The answer said runtime error, so I need to write code more shorter. 
This code is work. Thank you. Maybe I need to study map method more

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. :)

```py
casting = [  (int(i), int(j)) for i,j in L ] 
sumVariable = [ sum(i) for i in casting ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

alpha = [int(x[0])+int(x[1]) for x in L]